# Firebase Google Authentication works on localhost, but not on Netlify hosted site

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, google-signin, netlify

I have a React website that I'm hosting and deploying through Netlify. I have it currently set up so that I'm able to log in using their authentication service, which is useful. However, it only works on my Localhost. When I try to use it on the Netlify hosted site, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Illegal url for new iframe - https://%22trail-app-7d2e3.firebaseapp.com%22/__/auth/iframe?apiKey=********&appName=%5BDEFAULT%5D&v=9.2.0&eid=p&usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en.ILxaxn5iF9E.O%2Fam%3DAQ%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCP4GH4pdEaIiZe1k-cWfBRo9KTiAQ%2Fm%3D__features__#id=I0_1635906033796&_gfid=I0_1635906033796&parent=https%3A%2F%2Ftrailapp.netlify.app&pfname=&rpctoken=37134086
    at Object._.Zk (cb=gapi.loaded_0:154)
    at Fl (cb=gapi.loaded_0:165)
    at Object._.Gl (cb=gapi.loaded_0:166)
    at Object._.Nl (cb=gapi.loaded_0:172)
    at _.Ym.openChild (cb=gapi.loaded_0:310)
    at _.Ym.open (cb=gapi.loaded_0:315)
    at iframe.ts:81
    at l (runtime.js:63)
    at Generator._invoke (runtime.js:294)
    at Generator.next (runtime.js:119)
```

It seems as though it's trying to use that URL to reference a script that presents the iframe with the Google login. I'm not sure what permissions would be causing it not to work. I've enabled everything I know to.

I am using a .env file to hide my API information from a repository and have the values set up under "Environment Variables" on Netlify. If anyone has any feedback it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Be careful, your API key is in the URL in the message.

Comment: Have you added the Netlify URL to the authorized domains in Firebase? `localhost` is provided by default and so should always work

Comment: @DazWilkin I added it in my authorized domains, hasn't worked so far

Comment: Can you explain why your host name appears quoted in your message. It shows as `https://%22trail-app-7d2e3.firebaseapp.com%22`. The `%22` are URL-encoded `"`. So `https://"trail-app-7d2e3.firebaseapp.com"`

Comment: I’m not entirely sure - I’ll look more into it.

Comment: In Firebase, that’s the url that you pass to the database variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238848/discussion-between-quinton-price-and-dazwilkin).

Comment: It seems as though it's trying to use that URL to reference a script that presents the iframe with the Google login. I'm not sure what permissions would be causing it not to work. I've enabled everything I know to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your hosted domain in firebase [as I have added my own domain here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwfCW.png).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).